# Symfony - Doctrine Custom Query For Loading Associate Mapping Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

How can I customize the query for doctrine associate mapping load?

**Assumption**

1. Two tables in database which are user and item
2. There is an attribute named is_deleted (boolean) in the item table, when the value is set to true mean it is deleted.
3. Project setup with Symfony3

**Scenario**

For example, I have 2 entities class which are User and Item. The relationship between these 2 entities is **one-to-many** (each user can have many items).

When I try to get a user, the associated items will be loaded (lazy, eager, extra lazy) to that user as well.

What I try to achieve is to customize the associate mapping load where only load the items with is_deleted equal to false. How can I do this?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('Item')
   ->from('XYZBUNDLE:Item', 'Item')
   ->leftJoin('XYZBUNDLE:User', 'User')
   ->where('Item.is_deleted', ':is_deleted')
   ->andWhere('User.id', ':userId')
   ->setParameter('is_deleted', false)
   ->setParameter('userId', 1)
->getQuery()->getResult();
```

here you can remove where condition for user if you want to fetch all results for all users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I know this query can help to eliminate item with value equal to true. However, is it doable on the associate loading? Meaning when I load my user, the item auto loaded with the is_deleted equal false.

Comment: it will also work with non associated you can use it like 
    ->from('XYZBUNDLE:Item', 'Item')
    ->leftJoin('XYZBUNDLE:User', 'User', 'Item.user_id = User.id')

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter system of Doctrine, Maybe.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

I didn't try it.